# Azure Application Insights HTTP Dependency Tracking Issue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a very interesting case with one my applications. To start with, same/similar implementations works fine with my other projects.

Now my main problem is, in this specific project, HTTP remote dependency is not getting tracking. However, everything else is tracked such as normal performance, response times, server requests, custom events, custom exceptions SQL Dependencies. Just the HTTP dependency is not. They used to be tracking and out of nowhere they are not working anymore - this happened without publishing anything to server on the existing production server.

I'm using latest version of the AI packages 2.2.0 and 2.0.7, depending on the package. To point it out again, other projects are fine.

I have tried and checked this behaviour for this project for both Cloud Service and App Service in Azure. Both the same result. I have check tracking logs on debug, I can see SQL and Custom Event tracking but no record for HTTP calls again. Nothing unusual on the Output logs.

Last thing I want to mention is that, I'm deploying this service to multiple cloud services with different Instrument Keys and because of that this is the way I initialise my AI.

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AzureApplicationInsights");
```

I have also tried by setting everything into one AI resource via Visual Studio and observed same behaviour.

I'm not sure what else I can add, especially in code level but Azure support wasn't help too much so far, and this is kinda getting important for me as I'm not able see full performance of my system and this putting me in the blind spot for dependency errors.

Edit:

Just to add up, I'm using .Net 4.6.2 with System.Net.Http 4.3.0

Comment: Can you please clarify on "AI packages 2.2.0 and 2.0.7". What package is what version?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as a last test, I have downgraded System.Net.Http to 4.0.0 from 4.3.0 and locally it tracked dependency now.

Comment: Have you had any further information with your investigation? We have a similar issue where one project is able to track HTTP dependency calls but the other cannot. The one that does track has no NuGet reference to System.Net.Http and the one that does not track has NuGet reference to System.Net.Http. I will be testing it out but I'd also like to know why is System.Net.Http causing issues with AI.